# SAS for following scenario (most frequent observation)

Tags: sas

Assume I have a data-set `D1` as follows:

```
ID   ATR1   ATR2   ATR3  
1     A      R     W
2     B      T     X
1     A      S     Y
2     C      T     E
3     D      U     I
1     T      R     W
2     C      X     X
```

I want to create a data-set `D2` from this as follows

```
ID   ATR1   ATR2   ATR3  
1     A      R      W
2     C      T      X
3     D      U      I
```

In other words, Data-set `D2` consists of unique IDs from `D1`. For each ID in `D2`, the values of ATR1-ATR3 are selected as the most frequent (of the respective variable) among the records in `D1` with the same ID. For example ID = 1 in `D2` has ATR1 = A (most frequent).

I have one solution which is very clumsy. I simply sort copies of the data set `D1' three times (by ID and ATR1 e.g) and remove duplicates. I later merge the three data-sets to get what I want. However, I think there might be an elegant way to do this. I have about 20 such variables in the original data-set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* 
read and restructure so we end up with:

id attr_id value 
1 1 A
1 2 R
1 3 W
etc.
*/

data a(keep=id attr_id value);
length value $1;
array attrs_{*} $ 1 attr_1 - attr_3;
infile cards;
input id attr_1 - attr_3;
do attr_id=1 to dim(attrs_);
    value = attrs_{attr_id};
    output;
end;
cards;
1     A      R     W
2     B      T     X
1     A      S     Y
2     C      T     E
3     D      U     I
1     T      R     W
2     C      X     X
;
run;

/* calculate frequencies of values per id and attr_id */
proc freq data=a noprint;
tables id*attr_id*value / out=freqs(keep=id attr_id value count);
run;

/* sort so the most frequent value per id and attr_id ends up at the bottom of the group.
   if there are ties then it's a matter of luck which value we get */
proc sort data = freqs; 
by id attr_id count; 
run;

/* read and recreate the original structure. */ 
data b(keep=id attr_1 - attr_3);
retain attr_1 - attr_3;
array attrs_{*} $ 1 attr_1 - attr_3;
set freqs;
by id attr_id;
if first.id then do;
    do i=1 to dim(attrs_);
        attrs_{i} = ' '; 
    end;
end;
if last.attr_id then do; 
    attrs_{attr_id} = value;
end;
if last.id then do;
    output;
end;
run;
```